# Append HTML Radio button options to Python Flask URL

Tags: python, html, flask

I've looked around but can't seem to find an answer. I've an html form with radio button options in it. I'm trying to append them to the flask url when the results are posted based on the user input on the html page.

**Here is my html page:**

```
<form class="form-search" id="formdata" action="{{url_for('users')}}" method="post">
    <label><font size="4">Select option:</font></label>
    <div class="labeltext btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
       <label class="btn btn-primary active">
          <input type="radio" name="radioOptions" id="option1" value="Option1" checked> Option1 </label>
       <label class="btn btn-primary">
          <input type="radio" name="radioOptions" id="Option2" value="Option2"> Option2 </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My Flask View:**

```
@app.route('/users/<selectOption>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users(selectOption):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      radioOptions = request.form['radioOptions']
     return redirect (url_for('users', selectOption=selectOption))
return render_template('users.html')
```

I'm ending up with error

> TypeError: users() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Unsure what's going wrong from my end. I'm trying to make my url something look like below:

localhost:8080/users?radioOptions=Option1

Answer (score 0):

```
TypeError: users() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

The above error you get explains it all. In the following code :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
      radioOptions = request.form['radioOptions']
     return redirect (url_for('users', selectOption=selectOption))
```

You redirect to `users` while submitting the radio option.The `users` expects an argument which you have not provided yet ,i.e it is changeable and that is why you are getting this error.**Plus you are also not using your radioOptions value which you retrieve from this line**

```
selectOption = request.form['radioOptions']  #I have changed radioOptions to selectOption
```

The correct and cleaner way would be to define another function which renders your template and call it then in your redirect call , something like this :

```
@app.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      selectOption = request.form['radioOptions']
     return redirect (url_for('call_selected', selectOption=selectOption))
    return render_template('users.html')


@app.route('/<selectOption>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def call_selected(selectOption):
    return render_template(selectOption)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response with most appropriate answer. I think I was able to understand what went wrong. But what exactly I'm trying to achieve is a url like the following:

`users?radioOptions=option1& .. so on`

But when I always end up with the url like:

`users/option1` with errors. Trying to get this straighten again.

Comment: That seems like you are trying to pass parameters as query string . That is only possible in GET requests. POST doesn't show parameter passed as query string.

Comment: @Ray Did it help ? Did you get to your problem ?

Comment: Yep it works if I create a new function with new html page. But if I try to tweak the existing code, the results are adverse. Trying to figure out the best way to get this implemented. Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks @0decimal0 for helping me with this. I was able to get this issue resolved. Of course, I understand this is too late, but due to additional responsibilities and priorities I couldn't get time to work on this task.

Comment: @Ray If this answer helped you please upvote it or accept as an answer. :) Thanks.